# Опустить страницу вниз при открывании аккордеона

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Есть  аккордеон,он прекрасно работает,но вот при открытии первых разделов в принципе нормально,а вот когда открываю разделы в конце,они открываются но их не видно,приходится скролить страницу,затем при закрытии скролл пропадает,если был.
Вопрос: как сделать,что бы при открытии разделов страница вниз переходила?
Ниже пример структуры одного сектора,а дальше [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/hhqxjaf5/1/).

```js
//uses classList, setAttribute, and querySelectorAll
//if you want this to work in IE8/9 youll need to polyfill these
(function(){
 var d = document,
 accordionToggles = d.querySelectorAll('.js-accordionTrigger'),
 setAria,
 setAccordionAria,
 switchAccordion,
  touchSupported = ('ontouchstart' in window),
  pointerSupported = ('pointerdown' in window);
  
  skipClickDelay = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.click();
  }

  setAriaAttr = function(el, ariaType, newProperty){
  el.setAttribute(ariaType, newProperty);
 };
 setAccordionAria = function(el1, el2, expanded){
  switch(expanded) {
      case "true":
       setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'true');
       setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'false');
       break;
      case "false":
       setAriaAttr(el1, 'aria-expanded', 'false');
       setAriaAttr(el2, 'aria-hidden', 'true');
       break;
      default:
    break;
  }
 };
//function
switchAccordion = function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var thisAnswer = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
 var thisQuestion = e.target;
 if(thisAnswer.classList.contains('is-collapsed')) {
  setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'true');
 } else {
  setAccordionAria(thisQuestion, thisAnswer, 'false');
 }
   thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
   thisQuestion.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
  thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-collapsed');
  thisAnswer.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
  
   thisAnswer.classList.toggle('animateIn');
 };
 for (var i=0,len=accordionToggles.length; i<len; i++) {
  if(touchSupported) {
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('touchstart', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    if(pointerSupported){
      accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', skipClickDelay, false);
    }
    accordionToggles[i].addEventListener('click', switchAccordion, false);
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato';
}

.heading-primary {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion dl,
.accordion-list {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.accordion dl:after,
.accordion-list:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2ba659;
}

.accordion dd,
.accordion__panel {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.accordion p {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
}

.accordionTitle,
.accordion__Heading {
  background-color: #38cc70;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
          transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #30bb64;
}
.accordionTitle:before,
.accordion__Heading:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.accordionTitle:hover,
.accordion__Heading:hover {
  background-color: #2ba659;
}

.accordionTitleActive,
.accordionTitle.is-expanded {
  background-color: #2ba659;
}
.accordionTitleActive:before,
.accordionTitle.is-expanded:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-225deg);
          transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 50em;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
          transition: max-height 1s;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 15em;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
            transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
}

.accordionItem.is-collapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}

.no-js .accordionItem.is-collapsed {
  max-height: auto;
}

.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation: accordionIn 0.65s normal ease-in-out both 1;
          animation: accordionIn 0.65s normal ease-in-out both 1;
}

.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation: accordionOut 0.75s alternate ease-in-out both 1;
          animation: accordionOut 0.75s alternate ease-in-out both 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
            transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
            transform-origin: 50% 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
            transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
            transform-origin: 50% 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
            transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
            transform: scale(0.9) rotateX(-60deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
          <h1 class="heading-primary">CSS Responsive Animated Accordion</h1>
          <div class="accordion">
            <dl>
              <dt>
                <a href="#accordion1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion1" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">First Accordion heading</a>
              </dt>
              <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion1" aria-hidden="true">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
                <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
              </dd>
              <dt>
                <a href="#accordion2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion2" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">
                  Second Accordion heading</a>
              </dt>
              <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion2" aria-hidden="true">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
                <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
              </dd>
              <dt>
                <a href="#accordion3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion3" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">
                  Third Accordion heading
                </a>
              </dt>
              <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion3" aria-hidden="true">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
                <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
              </dd> <dt>
                <a href="#accordion3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion3" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">
                  Fourth Accordion heading
                </a>
              </dt>
              <dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion3" aria-hidden="true">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu interdum diam. Donec interdum porttitor risus non bibendum. Maecenas sollicitudin eros in quam imperdiet placerat. Cras justo purus, rhoncus nec lobortis ut, iaculis vel ipsum. Donec dignissim arcu nec elit faucibus condimentum. Donec facilisis consectetur enim sit amet varius. Pellentesque justo dui, sodales quis luctus a, iaculis eget mauris. </p>
                <p>Aliquam dapibus, ante quis fringilla feugiat, mauris risus condimentum massa, at elementum libero quam ac ligula. Pellentesque at rhoncus dolor. Duis porttitor nibh ut lobortis aliquam. Nullam eu dolor venenatis mauris placerat tristique eget id dolor. Quisque blandit adipiscing erat vitae dapibus. Nulla aliquam magna nec elementum tincidunt.</p>
              </dd>
            </dl>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть готовый jQuery-плагин -
[Page Scroll to ID](https://github.com/malihu/page-scroll-to-id)

```
$("#accordion1").mPageScroll2id();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function scrollToBottom (el) { 
    if (el ) el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, в чем сложность покрутить колесо мыши вниз, но можно сделать так. На js. Получаете текущее положение scrollTop(). При клике на нужные пункты меню (можно через селекторы типа :eq(n)) задание значение scrollTop(),относительно текущего,  которое вас визуально устроит, либо на высоту контейнера, который в гармошке.

Comment: В том то и дело,пробовал и прокрутить и ссылку на нижний блок делал,никак чет не хочет